# installing python packages Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, ubuntu-14.04

I'm having troubles installing python (2.7.6) modules in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have just tried to install module numpy (and others) and when I import it, I have the following output:

```
python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
from . import add_newdocs
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
from .polynomial import *
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 19, in <module>
from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq, inv
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
from .linalg import *
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 29, in <module>
from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg
ImportError: /usr/local/bin/gex/libgfortran.so.3: version `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found (required by /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3)
```

I already tried to update, upgrade, install with pip and so many other things and just became withouot extra options to try around here...

Could anyone give any light on what the problem might be?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Comment: Can you please show the installation command you used and the output from the installation (maybe from the shell history)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jkalden . The 1st thing I tried was to use native Ububtu 14.04 LTS python, which gave me forementioned error message. That´s the reason I tried to update. I tried the following:
    > sudo apt-get install python-numpy
    > sudo apt-get install python-scipy

Because it didn´t work, then I tried:
    > sudo pip install numpy

I also defined PYTHONPATH:
    PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/:$PYTHONPATH:$PATH

I also trying removing and reinstalling the numpy:
    sudo apt-get remove python-numpy
    sudo apt-get install python-numpy

...

Comment: Did you get any exceptional response or did the installation run smoothly? Actually, I always install python by `sudo apt-get install python*`...
Do you have 32bit or 64bit ubuntu?

Comment: Thanks again @jkalden

I didn´t really install phyton...only the needed modules/packages. Installation runs OK. The outcomes after the installation state that the the newst version is already installed...

Can it be that I have an old (or not standard) libgfortran.so.3? (last line in the error message) ? If so, what packages/updates should I install/update to get a functional one?

I´m using a 64bit ubuntu.

Comment: The library `libgfortran.so.3` comes with `gfortran`. Do you have it installed? 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: 64bit

Yes, I do have gfortran installed (4.8).

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to everyone who read and tried to help, specially @jkalden. I managed to reinstall gfortran manually by downloading the package (deb file). Everything is working fine...so far...!

Once again, thank you all for the inputs.